# How to run bash script from macro shell?

Tags: bash, shell, libreoffice-calc

How can I create a macro (for instance LibreOffice calc) that runs a bash script in terminal (for instance xfce4-terminal). An example:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world"
echo "Press any key to close this window"
read
```

I tried the Shell command in macro editor, but nothing happened. Here is what I did:

```
Sub testMysql
Shell ("/mnt/save/janos/home/testbashsql",4)
end Sub
```

It compiles and runs without error, but no output. As a side question: what does "compile" mean in this context, i.e. what happens to the compiled code? where is it stored? Why is there a "compile" button?
Thanks for helping me better understand macros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling the script will execute the script in a shell.  To see results, the script should write to a file rather than stdout, because LibreOffice does not display stdout.

To open a terminal instead, call the terminal.  This worked on my system.

```
Shell("xterm")
```

Regarding the compile button in the LO IDE, I use it to check Basic code for any syntax errors.  I am not aware of any compiled stored code.  Documentation is at https://help.libreoffice.org/Basic/Compile.

Comment: Thanks, it works. I did not realize xterm was available in my xubuntu 16.04 distro. I was struggling with xfce4-terminal as the argument of Shell(). The reason I needed the terminal is because my bash program is to perform a mysql command from within Calc that is linked to mysql. Great help!

Comment: forgot to show what works: `Shell("xterm -e /mnt/save/janos/home/testbashsql")`

Comment: Glad it worked.  However normally from Calc, the way to access MySQL is through LibreOffice Base, possibly using a macro as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41913754/5100564).

Comment: Yes, and thanks for the link. I only have primitive knowledge of macro-basic. Your example will help me to play with, and learn more about macros and their connections to mysql. In my case the "testbashsql" is a bash executable manipulating a mysql database.